# Change DropDownlist Selected Item Text After Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have large serverside bound dropdownlist with items similar to as follows:

- Item 1 (Live)
- Item 2 (Live)
- Item 3 (Offline)

When I change the status of each item instead of rebinding the list from the server side straight away I just want to update the selected item text until the user re-loads the page again.

I am calling a service via ajax to do the serverside work and I want to make this change when it's successful, but not matter what I do to the dropdown it never affects it.

This is the part I am having a problem with:

```
      $.ajax('/services/area/somefunction', {
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
               Id: id               
            },
            success: function (xhr, message, error) {  

            //do various stuff and then update dropdown    
            $("option:selected", ddl).text('test');    

            },    
            error: function (xhr, message, error) {
              // alert user of error

            }

        });
        return false;
    };
```

This is my HTML code for the dropdown:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_items" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="chosen-select"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and some other jquery parts for further info:

```
 // Initialiser
CustomStuff.Init = function () {
    ddl = document.getElementById('ddl_items');       
    $(ddl).on('change', getInfoForItem);
}
```

On change of the ddl

```
  function getInfoForItem(e) {
    //get the ID
    var id = e.target.value;
  //do stuff with this ID and hide and show some divs
   //and populate some values

}
```

I have tried changing the index of the dropdown and the .html but nothing seems to work.
I show and hide various divs in the success and that works, but why can I not seem to change the dropdown item text?

Comment: What is "ddl" ? There's nothing wrong with the given code snippet. Just make sure ddl is a correct selector. Also check the developer console for errors.

Comment: Try setting the property AutoPostBack="false" for the status drop down list, so it does not post back when status is changed. Also, can you post the markup for the status drop down list?

Comment: please share html code also.

Comment: @vendettamit There are no errors showing in the console. If I run debug mode  in chrome it steps through i but does nothing.
I have added some HTML code.

Comment: @Sunil The dropdown doesn't postback to change the status. It's another button you're pressing thats doing a load of stuff (including the extract above)